# Google Places API - how to get the address coordinates instead of the place's

Tags: google-places-api

I'm using Google Places API to get a geolocation of the place. I get the points and are able to place it correctly. Searching for the place below the marker is placed in the middle of the building.

https://www.google.com/maps/place/C.D.E.-Centro+de+Diagnostico+de+Elvas,+Lda/@38.8799378,-7.1615604,20.05z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0xd171c6f3bfd342f:0xe99e4c47a055bae3!8m2!3d38.8799892!4d-7.161476

Now what I'm looking for is to place the marker on the address of the building (basically the door) which would be here:

https://www.google.com/maps/place/R.+de+S%C3%A3o+Louren%C3%A7o+17,+7350-026+Elvas/@38.8800482,-7.1619366,19z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0xd171c691f19dac7:0xe21f4232dc70c067!8m2!3d38.8800482!4d-7.1613894

The only way of doing this right now is to get the place, get the place detail and then, using the address making another call for the new coordinate.

Is this the only way to get the geolocation of a place's address?

Answer (score 1):

[Reverse geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro) is your best friend!

Input your address like so, taking out the spaces.

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=R.deSãoLourenço17,7350-026,Elvas&key=API_KEY`

Then access the coordinates via the `geometry` field. Hope this helps.